# Timing word-searching code in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, benchmarking

I'm using a linear search as a spell checker. I need to time my code to get averages as I'm using different searches and comparing them. However I don't believe the code I've used to time the code is accurate enough or the best method. If anyone has any suggestion that would be great.

```
import re
import time

start_time = time.time()
f1=open('writefile.txt', 'w+')

def linS(target, words):
    '''linear search for target in words. words need not be sorted'''
    for s in words:
        if s==target:
            return True
    return False

words = [s.strip("\n").lower() for s in open("dict.txt")] 
words.sort() # sort the list

with open("text.txt" , encoding="utf8") as text:
    content = text.read().split(" ")
    content = [item.lower() for item in content]
    content = ' '.join(content)
    content = re.findall("[a-z]+", content)

for w in content:
    if not linS(w, words):
        f1.write(w+'\n')

f1.close()

print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
```

Comment: Did you consider using the [`timeit`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html) module?

Comment: @GarethRees I looked into it but couldnt really grasp it

Comment: Why do you not consider this to be accurate?

Comment: @l0b0 I assumed it would time how long it takes to write to the file as well as the time to carry out the searches. Would this not make a difference?

Comment: It times whatever you have wrapped it around, yes. But what are you trying to time? `findall`? `linS`? Defining the problem is going to be very useful.

Comment: @l0b0 yes im trying to time linS. I want to time the actual searches not the time it takes to write to the file with the results

Answer (score 2):

Some suggestions:

- Pass the code through `pycodestyle` to make it more idiomatic.
- Use `with open()` (or `try`/`finally` for a more complicated solution) to make sure files are closed whenever they are done with.
- You can do `.readlines()` on a file pointer to avoid `strip`ping newlines.
- The dictionary is presumably controlled by you. Sort and lower-case it once, and then you don't have to do that every time the script runs.
- These are logically equivalent:

  ```
      for x in y:
          if x == target:
              return True
      return False
  ```

  and

  ```
      return target in y
  ```
- Use descriptive names such as `for word in words` and `def linear_search.
- Put the timing code around the lines you are trying to time. If you want to know the aggregate time of `linS` then get the start and end times just before and just after the last loop (which will count the time it takes to write to disk buffers) or accumulate a sum of run times *within* `linS`.